# Am I required to link with an external library whose functionality I am not using in the current library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries, static-linking

I have `library A` where some functionality in it requires `library B`. `library A` has two independent classes `F` and `G` *(i.e. `F` and `G` do not know about each other)* where `G` includes headers from `library B` in its `cpp` file, thus the dependency of `library A` on `library B` because of class `G`. `F` does *not* use any functionality from `library B`.

I now have an executable `E` that uses `F` but **not** `G`. Am I required to link against `library B` even though I am not using any functionality from `library A` that uses `library B`? If yes, is there any way to avoid that without splitting up `library A` into two libraries?

I was under the assumption that you don't have to link against the external library unless you are using its functionality somehow.

Comment: I've found linking against a static library *A* **that uses another library *B* but didn't link against it** needs that I explicitly link against *B*.

Comment: @faranwath: Right, but what if I am not using any functionality from `B`? That is, I don't call any functions in `A` or instantiate any classes in `A` that use functionality from `B`? Am I still required to link against `B`? If yes, why? Why do symbols from `B` need to be linked at all if they are not used in my executable?

Comment: Well, I'm no expert at all, but I'd think you shouldn't need to link against `B` at all if none of its data is being used. Perhaps `A` is indeed using something that `B` offers, but it's somehow hidden from you.

Comment: @Faranwath: That's exactly it :) before trying to find out the source, I thought I'd confirm that this is the standard behavior (that library `B` doesn't need to be linked unless it is being used directly or indirectly by the executable) and if it isn't, well, I'll (grudgingly) link with `B` :)

Comment: I just tried a similar scenario out with VS2013 and whether or not it looks for Lib B depends on whether there is call to a lib B function in the same source file (hence same object file) as the functions that are called from the executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not necessary.  A static library is a very simple file format, it is just a bag of .obj files.  The linker only pulls in the .obj files that it need to resolve a dependency in your main program.  Or an .obj file that was pulled in that in turn requires another one to be used.  You only get a linker error when symbols are still unresolved after it looked at the available .obj files.

A sample implementation of the G class I tried to double-check this, in g.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "a.h"

void foo();    // Defined in b.lib

G::G() {
    foo();
}
```

And tested in a program that looked like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\a\a.h"


int main()
{
    F obj;
    //G obj2;
    return 0;
}
```

It linked just fine without linking b.lib.  Removing the comment from obj2 produced the expected LNK2019 error for foo().

---

Plenty of ways that this might not pan-out in practice.  Pretty hard to see dependencies with an unaided eye.  And the unit of linkage is an object file, g.obj in the above example.  So it is important that your F class members are defined in a *different* source code file than your G class members.  In other words, you need a separate f.obj and g.obj file in a.lib.

This can be tinkered with, the /Gy compile option can package individual functions each in a separate section.  Which lights up the /OPT:REF linker option, the unit of linkage now becomes an individual function instead of an object file.  But that's a pretty high price to pay, it only improves the final size of the executable and doesn't remove the need to still have to link b.lib.  And it disables incremental linking and may require tinkering with the original library projects.  As long as you need to do that, just easier to keep the code for F and G in separate source files.

The linker's /VERBOSE option can provide insight, it shows you what is being pulled in and which .obj file caused a dependency to be linked.  Enter it in the Linker + Command Line, Additional Options box.

Answer (score 0):

When you link to a *static* library, what the linker does is to pick out of the library the object files defining symbols used by the program. So if you don't reference G, it won't be included in the program. That happens if you add the respective static library when linking or not.

Comment: That is what I thought as well until I started getting linking errors for using `library A` where the linker wanted to link against `library B` even though I wasn't using any of the functionality of `library A` that used `library B` symbols.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit dependency between library A and library B. You may not have to link explicitly depending on the compiler you're using. But there is a fair chance that during its execution it is going to look for library B. In windows, there is an option to delay load a DLL - which means an attempt to load library B is not done unless the code path is hit.